# Tooltip in Google Chart while populating chart using JSON with multiple line

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

Using stackoverflow i'm doing my own chart with Google.
I've read this:
[Tooltip in Google Chart while populating chart using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174562/tooltip-in-google-chart-while-populating-chart-using-json/19793301#19793301) and with this "instruction" i've tried to do with myself a multi line chart with custom tooltip but without results.

I've tried something like that

```
{"cols": [{"id": "", "label": "Date", "type": "string"},
    {"id": "", "label": "price", "type": "number"},
    {"id": "", "role": "tooltip", "type": "string", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" } } 
    {"id": "", "label": "price2", "type": "number"},
    {"id": "", "role": "tooltip", "type": "string", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" } } 
],
"rows": [
    {"c":[{"v": "Apr 24th","f":"null"}, {"v": 56000,"f":"56000"}, {"v": "24 April, Price - 56000, Seller-abcd"}, {"v": 50000,"f":"56000"}, {"v": "24 April, Price - 56000, Seller-abcd"}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "May 3rd","f":"null"}, {"v": 68000,"f":"68000"}, {"v": "3 May, Price - 68000, Seller-abcd"}, {"v": 56000,"f":"56000"}, {"v": "24 April, Price - 56000, Seller-abcd"}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "May 13th","f":"null"}, {"v": 50400,"f":"50400"}, {"v": "23 May, Price - 50000, Seller-abcd"}, {"v": 56000,"f":"56000"}, {"v": "24 April, Price - 66000, Seller-abcd"}]}
]}
```

What is wrong in that? I want to specify that: with single line (copying the code of the link above) this works fine and i've my good chart :D
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your first tooltip column:

```
"cols": [
    {"id": "", "label": "Date", "type": "string"},
    {"id": "", "label": "price", "type": "number"},
    {"id": "", "role": "tooltip", "type": "string", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" } }, // <--- need a comma here
    {"id": "", "label": "price2", "type": "number"},
    {"id": "", "role": "tooltip", "type": "string", "p" : { "role" : "tooltip" } } 
]
```

Comment: Thank u bro, i'm so tired and for me this comma is like ... COMA!